# Docker-Compose file has yaml.scanner.ScannerError

Tags: docker, yaml, docker-compose, dockerfile

`compose.yml` file, which looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  discovery-microservice:
    build: discovery-microservice
      context: /discovery-microservice/target/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"
```

While I am executing it I get the following error:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
in "C:\...\docker-compose.yml", line 5, column 14
```

From what I see, nothing is wrong with the format, e.g. whitespaces missing. My overall goal is to specify a development mode docker-compose file, pointing it to the target directories from the different modules.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That's because `context:` and `dockerfile:` are shifted forward - align them with `build:`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Literally found the solution seconds later. You have to remove the "discovery-microservice" after "build":

```
version: '2'
services:
  discovery-microservice:
    build:
      context: ./discovery-microservice/target/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8761:8761"
```

Also you can use "./" in context for relative paths. :)

Comment: build on it's own defaults to build [context]. If you add args, you need to move the [contex] down and leave build on it's own

Comment: Thanks this was the issue. I had `build: .` now removed the '.' its working fine

Answer (score 164):

Ok, I wasted around 3 hours to debug a similar issue.

If you guys ever get the below error

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 9
```

It's because a space is needed between

`version:'3'`   <-- this is wrong

`version: '3'`   <-- this is correct.

Also, if you are using eclipse, do yourself a favor and install the YEdit YAML editor plugin

Comment: I got similar issue, but actually when you use an editor with adequate plugin, you avoid such mistake thanks to coloration syntax !!

Comment: My variant was that I was missing the colon after the word version 'version*:* 3'

Answer (score 19):

And I forgot `:` after `version`

```
version '2'
```

Answer (score 6):

What is wrong is that here:

```
    build: discovery-microservice
```

you start a mapping which has a key `build` indented by four spaces. The value for that key is a scalar that starts with `discovery-microservice` and possible continues to the next line, depending on whether that has a `key: value` pair **at the same indentation level** or not

What is not allowed inside such a multiline scalar is that you have an unquoted `:` **and** have that at a different indentation level. Which is exactly what you do have.

The parser seeing `context` indented at a different level than `build` assumes you are writing a scalar string `discovery-microservice context` which cannot be followed on the same line (as `context`) by a colon.

Apart from removing `discovery-microservice` after build as you did in your answer, what would also make this valid YAML (but with a different meaning, probably non-sense for docker compose) are:

```
services:
  discovery-microservice:
    build: "discovery-microservice
      context: /discovery-microservice/target/docker"
```

and

```
services:
  discovery-microservice:
    build: discovery-microservice
    context: /discovery-microservice/target/docker"
```

For docker-compose version 2 files, the `build` key expects a mapping (and not a scalar as in the "solutions" above), making your answer the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

I met same issue and I think it's might be your yaml file format is invalid. So in order to solve it, first **we need to make sure our yaml file format is valid**

below is your original code snippet

```
version: '2'
services:
  discovery-microservice:
    build: discovery-microservice
      context: /discovery-microservice/target/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"
```

If we use **http://www.yamllint.com/** check the yaml file, we will get error as below:
[image]

Then we change it as below:

```
services: 
  discovery-microservice: 
    build: discovery-microservice
    context: /discovery-microservice/target/docker
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports: 
    - "8761:8761"
version: "2"
```

after checking it, we will get result as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bringing my answer because while I got the same error message, my solution was different.

**Original docker-compose.yml**

```
volumes: mongo:
```

After trying all the ideas in this thread I just went to the docker-compose docks and realized that volumes should be structured like:

```
volumes:
  mongo:
```

That's it for anyone else running into this.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you have context and dockerfile at the same identation. I made a mistake and was stuck for hours.

My error was

> ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here 
>   in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 19

Wrong:

```
version : '3'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: ./test
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    image: kpod/test:2020
```

Right:

```
version : '3'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: ./test
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    image: kpod/test:2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi further update to the given answer .... It's not specifically about the version: '2.0' line
The statement

> ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here

means there's a formatting error of some sort.

I got it and it was because I was missing a tab in my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  mysql:
  image: ...
```

instead of

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  mysql:
    image: ...
```

Note the lack of an indenting tab on the image line

Comment: Yes **indenting**  ,that was the mistake I made. I use `version : '3'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `vs code` do yourself a favor and install `YAML` extension by "RedHat".

Answer (score 1):

1) Give a space after every colon whenever you do mapping after defining key.

2) A YAML file  uses 2(two spaces or tabs) indentation.
-->It means that after every line you need to use two tabs,when you write a sentence in following line.
I hope this will make easy to write any YAML file now.

Answer (score 1):

Using the vs code yaml RedHat extension, I saw I was off by one indent:

Wrong:

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    image: nginx
     ports:
    - 9090:80

  database:
    image: redis
```

Right:

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - 9090:80

  database:
    image: redis
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that missing one `":"`, was enough to produce the above error

Comment: Colon blindness!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue today, a syntax error in the `docker-compose.yml` file that caused the same error.

```
version: '2'
services:
// Add your services here
  discovery-microservice:
    build: discovery-microservice
      context: ./discovery-microservice/target/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"
```

Removing this line `// Add your services here` fixed my issue

```
version: '2'
services:
  discovery-microservice:
    build:
      context: ./discovery-microservice/target/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8761:8761"
```

I hope this helps someone with a similar issue.

Comment: Some programmer probably thought that because BCPL had `//` as end-of-line comments that anything with a four letter acronym will have those. YAML comments start with a `#` preceded with white-space (which includes a newline).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible culprit can be stray tabs at the end of the file, which I learned today.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Being rather familiar with the PyYAML source that docker-compose is using for parsing YAML, I think it is impossible that trailing tabs would cause the `mapping errors not allowed" error. Please provide a minimal example to sustain your claim.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a volume mapped to a specific path on the external (host) server. I tried putting that under the top-level `volumes` entry in `docker-compose.yml`. After looking at the docker-compose file docs, I realized that that type of volume does not go there. Instead, it goes only under the `volumes` entry within the container definition. E.g.:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: my_custom_web_image
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app/subdir:/usr/src/app/subdir
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your whitespaces [by validating your YAML input.](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator)

I spent 1hour to find out.

Answer (score 0):

So, there is another reason! 
When you try to install r=Redash using the setup.sh from the Github, the script automatically gets the latest version of Redash and put it in docker-compose.yml. The base yml file doesn't have single-quotations (') around version name! As a result, you get an error that says:

> ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
>     in "./docker-compose.yml", line 3, column 23
>   You just add single-quotation around the Redash version:

```html
version: "2"
x-redash-service: &redash-service
  image: 'redash/redash:8.0.0.b32245'
```

Answer (score 0):

**check for the space between**

ports:

- _space_ "8080:8080"

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was adding the space between `version: '2'`

Also useful, when stipulating what the context field is, using `./` or the actual absolute path where the Dockerfile resides resolved this error:

```
ERROR: build path /Users/name/somepath/someapp either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.
```